# different image

Tags: playn

I have two images, put them in a list and repeat the second image to get a list with four images, three equal and one different.

Before placing the images on the screen I call `Collections.shuffle` (myList).
The User has to click on any of the images.

How do I know if the User clicked on different image?

Answer (score 1):

What about instead of shuffling an image you shuffle a class?

```
class MyImage {
    MyImage(Image img, Boolean val, int x, int y){
      image = img;
      unique = val;
      posX = x;
      posY = y;
   }
}
```

You define a class like that, and add its coordinates and the boolean which defines if it is different.

Now you have to send the pointer event to the collection:

```
    public boolean isUnique(){
       return unique;
    }

    public void Intersects(int x, int y){
      if (x > posX && x < (posX + image.Width()) 
          && y > posY && y < (posY + image.Height())) {
            if (isUnique()) {
               // Perform action for unique image
            }
      } 
    }
```

So if the boolean you get is true, it means this is your unique image.

Comment: To add an Image on the screen, I add in ImageLayer. And ImageLayer only accepts object of type Image. How do I put in a MyImage ImageLayer?

Comment: Instead of  MyImage(Image img, Boolean val, int x, int y)
use  MyImage(ImageLayer img, Boolean val, int x, int y){